# Use Android activities with html files - Phonegap + Eclipse for Android

Tags: android, cordova, android-activity, eclipse-juno

I want to develop my **first** mobile application using Phonegap and Eclipse for Android OS. 

I've read many posts about how to make a simple mobile app. In all tutorials, you create the "index.html" file and that is what you see in your android phone after you build the app. I made this with no difficulties.

What I don't understand, is how can I use all these activities that the Eclipse has. For example I want to have in my application a **Navigation drawer**. How can I make this happen?

What i only have to do is to add those *activities* and work with the *xml files* of them or can I link my html file with those *activities*?

If anyone can send me a tutorial that will explain how exactly I can use those things, I would be grateful.

---

The activity that i added was *empty* but when I launch my app in my android phone, it appears for a second, disappears and then I can see my `index.html` page.

What I have right now in my `MainActivity.java` file is:

```
package com.example.guide_mefor_all;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;

public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
}
```

and in my `index.html` file i wrote:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Guide-Me For-All</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/home.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
     <div id="logo">
        <img id="lg" src="imgs/logo.png" alt="Logo">
     </div>
    <h1>Hello PhoneGap</h1>

 </body>
</html>
```

I also changed the  `AndroidManifest.xml` to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.guide_mefor_all"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"
    />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" 
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity 
            android:name="org.apache.cordova.DroidGap" 
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"> 
            <intent-filter></intent-filter> 
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check these links. I think the second post will help how to done in eclipse.

This is for installation and platform adding.
http://www.7solutions.in/2014/07/phone-gap-installation-in.html

And this is for the second setp after creating the project.
http://www.7solutions.in/2014/07/next-step-for-after-creating-phonegap.html

Comment: thanks for your link. Basically, I used this specific tutorial: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/getting-started-with-phonegap-in-eclipse-for-android.html . So, I used terminal only to install phonegap, node, git and ant and my html files are already created in eclipse after the creation of the android project.